# Below what percent of life you do not gain any crystals in fort conquer

Tags: android, fort-conquer

So i downloaded Fort Conquer on my cellphone and i tend to be very anal about my gameplay wanting everything to be perfect. I soon realized that in these kinda games its really difficult to accomplish that so i settled. I played for a while and i realized that when your life is low you do not get the crystal reward for life, which really upset me. Its seems like really huge waste for me. I just wonder under what percent i will not receive the crystal bonus (i think i had 1% of life when i finished the level)

Comment: If u click on question mark at the end of game, it explains clearly how and when and what you can get for winning and losing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its most likely 50% as I lost with 47% and didn't get a crystal and with 54% i did. 
It would seem logical that they would put it right in the middle but for some reason i thought it be some weird percent and it would take me forever to figure it out.

You can also gain crystals if you get defeated but you cause certain amount of damage to the opponent